# Move back button to original position with UIView.Animate

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiviewanimation

I'm creating 14 buttons programmatically in another function and I added target to them and get them animate each all, and I've targets when I press any button go the target, my problem **how to move back to original position with using** `UIView.Animate` **??**

Exactly like this Gif :

[image: Demo]

**Codes:**

```
var tileArrayXAxis: [Int] = [] // X-Axis of the my 14 buttons
var tileArrayYAxis: [Int] = [] // Y-Axis of the my 14 buttons
var tileArrayWidth: [Int] = [] // Width of the my 14 buttons
var tileArrayHeight: [Int] = [] // Heigh of the my 14 buttons

var targetArrayXAxis: [Int] = [] // X-Axis of the target
var targetArrayYAxis: [Int] = [] // Y-Axis of the target
var targetArrayWidth: [Int] = [] // Width of the target
var targetArrayHeight: [Int] = [] // Heigh of the target

var i : Int = 0

func moveButton(sender: UIButton) {

    var xS = Int()
    var yS = Int()
    var widthS = Int()
    var heightS = Int()

    if i < targetArrayXAxis.count && i < targetArrayYAxis.count && i < targetArrayWidth.count && i < targetArrayHeight.count {

        xS = targetArrayXAxis[i]
        yS = targetArrayYAxis[i]
        widthS = targetArrayWidth[i]
        heightS = targetArrayHeight[i]
        yS -= widthS

        let startS = CGPoint(x: xS, y: yS)

        let sizeS = CGSize(width: widthS, height: heightS)
        sender.frame = CGRect(x: startS.x, y: startS.y, width: sizeS.width, height: sizeS.width)

    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 6, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: { [weak self] in

        sender.transform = .identity
        self?.i += 1        
    })
}
```

Comment: sender.transform = .identity don't move back to original position ?

Comment: No @Arrabidas92

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting transform to identity after you’ve set the frame to a new value will not move the button at all, as it will just return the new frame.

Either: You need to store the old frame in a variable, before you set it to a new value:

```
let oldFrame : CGRect = sender.frame
// Now set the frame to its new value
sender.frame = ....
```

And then in your animation block:

```
sender.frame = oldFrame
```

Or: do not assign a new frame to sender but assign a translation transform to it, then set the transform to identity in the animation block to undo the transform and send the button back to where it was.

EDIT: As requested, a simple ViewController implementation of this as follows:

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
fileprivate var buttonOne : UIButton!
fileprivate var buttonTwo : UIButton!
fileprivate var buttonOneFrame : CGRect {
    return CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width / 2 - 200, y: 100),
    size: CGSize(width: 150, height: 100))
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    buttonOne = {
        let bO : UIButton = UIButton()
        bO.backgroundColor = .red
        bO.setTitle("Frame Method", for: .normal)
        bO.addTarget(self, action: #selector(frameMethodMove(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        bO.frame = buttonOneFrame
        return bO
    }()

    buttonTwo = {
        let bT : UIButton = UIButton()
        bT.backgroundColor = .blue
        bT.setTitle("Transform Method", for: .normal)
        bT.addTarget(self, action: #selector(transformMethodMove(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        bT.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width / 2 + 50, y: 100),
                          size: CGSize(width: 150, height: 100))
        return bT
    }()

    view.addSubview(buttonOne)
    view.addSubview(buttonTwo)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@objc fileprivate func frameMethodMove(sender: UIButton) -> Void {

    let newFrame : CGRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: buttonOneFrame.origin.x, y: buttonOneFrame.origin.y + 500),
                                   size: buttonOneFrame.size)

    sender.frame = newFrame

    sender.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(frameMethodMove(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    sender.addTarget(self, action: #selector(frameMethodMoveBack(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc fileprivate func frameMethodMoveBack(sender: UIButton) -> Void {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
        sender.frame = self.buttonOneFrame
    }, completion: ({ _ in

        sender.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(self.frameMethodMoveBack(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        sender.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.frameMethodMove(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }))

}

@objc fileprivate func transformMethodMove(sender: UIButton) -> Void {

    sender.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: 0, y: 500)

    sender.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(transformMethodMove(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    sender.addTarget(self, action: #selector(transformMethodMoveBack(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc fileprivate func transformMethodMoveBack(sender: UIButton) -> Void {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
        sender.transform = .identity
    }, completion: ({ _ in
        sender.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(self.transformMethodMoveBack(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        sender.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.transformMethodMove(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }))
}
```

}

Comment: I'm trying your solve but it's back to original position auto I want back to original position manually I mean by press it, How can I do that ??

Comment: Please look at my GIF and see how animation 4 buttons to target and skipped position and back to their original position by press their @Sparky

Comment: @user1.develop I understand what you are trying to do - returning the buttons with a click is trivial. You do it by splitting the methods into two, and replacing the button targets. For the frame method you also need to save the original button location as a class property (either that or subclass UIButton); in my opinion the transform method is probably more elegant. Please see my edit.